# Finding pinch-in or pinch-out in UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` on view, now I have a requirement of knowing whether pinch-in is performed or pinch-out is performed in my selector method. Either of 1 among at a time. Please give me some idea to obtain this. Thank you.

Answer (score 52):

Use the `.scale` property on the gesture:

- >1 pinch out
- <1 pinch in

Comment: For clarity here, as it was a bit confusing to me at first:
``scale > 1 = zoom in``
``scale < 1 = zoom out``